# How to set world lighting in editor same as blender viewport shading?

Tags: blender, godot, godot4

I have a `.blend` file imported from blender and due to the lighting it looks very different in godot.

The issue is that when I look "under the mesh" (rotate the view below) in godot there are dark shadows and hence I'm not able to clearly see the shapes, whereas this is not the case in blender due to `world space lighting` being disabled i.e. the lighting follows the camera.

So is there anything similar in Godot 4 which will let me clearly see the mesh no matter where I'm looking at it from the editor?

**Blender:**
[image]

**Godot:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the top of the viewport in the center the sun and globe icons (next to the Camera3D icon) control the preview sunlight and the preview environment respectively. If you disable the preview sunlight only the ambient lighting affects the mesh.

Comment: This does improve the overall view but still doesn't make it as clear as in blender, is there any other way?